# run a windows batch file from node.js

Tags: node.js, batch-file

am trying to run a test.bat file inside  node.js

here is the code

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

case '/start':
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {});
    req.on('end', function () {
      console.log("INSIDE--------------------------------:");      
       exec('./uli.bat', function (err, data) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
        res.end(data);
      });
    });
    break;
```

while running this node.js file am getting

```
INSIDE--------------------------------:
{ [Error: Command failed: '.' is not recognized as an internal or ext
nd,
operable program or batch file.
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

Comment: It would be better if you posted the full output, instead of an oddly cropped portion :). Also, that `./` path looks very unixy

Comment: it is the full output

Comment: Have you tried without the `./` in the path to the .bat file?

Answer (score 17):

I have found the solution for it.. and its works fine for me. This opens up a new command window and runs my main node JS in child process. You need not give full path of cmd.exe.
I was making that mistake.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
ls    = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'my.bat']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Comment: This does not work on window. Spawn works only on linux shell env.

Comment: I can confirm that this does, in fact, work in Windows to execute `.bat` files.

Comment: Under windows, in case you want to use relative path for the batch file; use template strings like so: `spawn('cmd.exe',["/c", \`..\\BINARIES\\t1.bat\`],{env: process.env});`

Comment: I get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". Anyone know why and how to fix that?

Comment: getting error as Uncaught Error: spawn when trying to use this

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I know for execute that is following code :

```
require('child_process').exec("path/to/your/file.bat", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
        // Ooops.
        // console.log(stderr);
        return console.log(err);
    }

    // Done.
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

You could replace `"path/to/your/file.bat"` by `__dirname + "/file.bat"` if your file is in the directory of your current script for example.

Comment: No matter how i try to do this, i get the same error:

`Error: Command failed: E:/devProj/instager/start.bat
ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:217:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'E:/devProj/instager/start.bat'`

Answer (score 5):

In Windows, I don't prefer spawn as it creates a new cmd.exe and we have to pass the .bat or .cmd file as an argument. `exec` is a better option. Example below:

Please note that in Windows you need to pass the path with double backslashes. E.g. `C:\\path\\batfilename.bat`

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec("path", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

An easier way I know for executing that is the following code :

```js
function Process() {
    const process = require('child_process');
    var ls = process.spawn('script.bat');
    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    ls.on('close', function (code) {
        if (code == 0)
            console.log('Stop');
        else
            console.log('Start');
    });
};

Process();
```