# Run batch file from Electron main thread

Tags: javascript, batch-file, electron

I'm attempting to run a simple batch file from my electron application. Here is my code:

```
globalShortcut.register('Control+B', () => {
    log.info('Batch File Triggered: ' + app.getAppPath() + '\\local\\print.bat')
    require('child_process').exec(app.getAppPath() + '\\local\\print.bat', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            // Ooops.
            // console.log(stderr);
            return console.log(err);
        }

        // Done.
        console.log(stdout);
    });
})
```

The batch file should be triggered when Control+B is pressed by the user, but it does not work. The log entry is made, and I've verified the path is correct, but the file is never actually launched.

I found these questions, which ask the same question, but these are 4 years old at this point and none of the answers have worked for me, there is no display, no error, nothing.

- [run a windows batch file from node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678933/run-a-windows-batch-file-from-node-js)
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557461/execute-a-batch-file-from-nodejs

I've also tried the child_process.spawn but that also did nothing noticeable.

```
var ls = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', app.getAppPath() + '\\local\\print.bat']);
```

How can I launch my batch file from my electron application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just discovered such an easy way to do this. You can use the electron shell module, like this:

```
const {shell} = require('electron');
// Open a local file in the default app
shell.openItem(app.getAppPath() + '\\local\\print.bat');
```

Comment: This works great.  Unfortunately, though, there doesn't appear to be a way to pass arguments with electron's `shell.openItem`.  I found that although node's `child_process.spawn` can't be used to spawn node to run a file in the .asar, if I copy the file from the .asar and it's dependencies to somewhere else, I can spawn node and run it.

Answer (score 1):

try using the code below

```
function Process() {
    const process = require('child_process');   
    var ls = process.spawn('script.bat');
    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    ls.on('close', function (code) {
       if (code == 0)
            console.log('Stop');
       else
            console.log('Start');
    });
};

Process();
```

not forgetting to run

```
npm install child_process
```

on your terminal

Comment: Are you able to pass arguments to the batch file with this?