# Electron run cmd as administrator

Tags: electron

I want to run the following cmds from my app to stop windows update:

```
sc config wuauserv start= disable
sc config bits start= disable
sc config DcomLaunch start= disable
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
net stop DcomLaunch
```

but they need administrator privileges to execute, do i need to run the app as administrator or can I execute only this script as administrator.

I am using this function to execute cmd:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function execute(command, callback) {
    exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        callback(stdout);
    });
};
```

Now I am not really sure if the script above does really stop the windows update or do I need to stop the updates from group policies on windows 10 pro. Also I was planing on running the above script line by line but is there a way to run it as a `.bat` file from electron?

Answer (score 0):

```
const {shell} = require('electron');
// Open a local file in the default app
shell.openItem(app.getAppPath() + '\\local\\print.bat');
```

You can use this code to run a .bat file as you where planning. In order to run a command as administrator in Electron (if I am correct), you just need to run the electron app as administrator.

For more information about running a bat file from electron, [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906156/run-batch-file-from-electron-main-thread) this site.