# Nodejs cannot read property of addEventListner Null

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying to make a button that runs command prompt to install software for my program my nodejs is,

```
$( "install" ).addEventListener('click',() => {
    var child_process = require('child_process');
    child_process.exec('test.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
})});
```

and html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-installer" id="install">Run Installer</button>
```

The js file is included in the html, when I run my app however it returns:

```
C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\tron-gui\index.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\tron-gui\index.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\tron-gui\index.js:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580)
    at Module.load (module.js:503)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458)
    at Module.require (module.js:513)
    at require (internal/module.js:11)
    at index.html:30
```

Help is appreciated test.bat is in the same folder as the GUI

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Node.js is a server side language and would not be anyway listen to events on your button.

What you are talking about is what Javascript is supposed to do.

Secondly, you need to use #install if you are referring to a button with id install in JQuery.

Thirdly, you are combining server side programming and client side programming together. You cannot trigger a child_process from Javascript. Thats a node.js API and hence you wouldn't be able to run the bat file you are looking to run.

Comment: Thanks for breaking the truth to me is there any easy way to do it? @Vignesh T.V.

Comment: @Ogden You need to listen for events using Javascript on the client side and then on the occurence of the event, you would need to call a server side API via AJAX which would trigger a child process which can run the bat file and then after completion send the output back. 
I suggest that you go through Javascript and Node.js first properly before getting started with this.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using electron is there by any chance something in electron that can do this sort of stuff?

Comment: @Ogden: If you are using electron, then this makes more sense. You should try using IPC Renderer for that. Refere this: https://coursetro.com/posts/code/122/Electron-IPC-Tutorial---Communication-within-your-Electron-App

Comment: Or this: https://discuss.atom.io/t/handling-click-events-in-the-dom/41642/2

Comment: how would I actually open the bat though?

Comment: Suggest you to look into these threads for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678933/run-a-windows-batch-file-from-node-js
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557461/execute-a-batch-file-from-nodejs
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906156/run-batch-file-from-electron-main-thread

Comment: $ ( "#install" ).addEventListener('click',() => {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'test.bat']);
    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });
    ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });
    ls.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
})

But do you know how to make it actually open a command prompt so users can see what is outputed instead of it going to console on my app?